# Solutions in a field

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, ordered-fields

Suppose $F$ is a field. Suppose further that $F$ is an ordered field. Consider the following equation $x^3 = b$, where $b \in F$. Prove that the equation above has, at most, one solution.

My attempt:

Suppose we have $x = b^{1/3} \in F$. We have that

$$x^3 = (b^{1/3})^3) = b^{\frac{1}{3} \cdot 3} = b^1 = b$$

Thus, there is one solution.

Assume there exists another solution and denote this by $c^{1/3}$. Since $b^{1/3}$ is a solution, $x = b^{1/3} \implies (b^{1/3})^3 = b \implies (b^{1/3})^3 - b = 0$. In a similar fashion, since $c^{1/3}$ is another solution, $x = c^{1/3} \implies (c^{1/3})^3 = b \implies (c^{1/3})^3 - b = 0$. Together we see that

$$(b^{1/3})^3 - b = 0 = (c^{1/3})^3 - b \implies (b^{1/3})^3 =(c^{1/3})^3 \implies b^{1/3} = c^{1/3} \implies b = c$$

Therefore there is at most one solution.

Is this correct for a field, $F$? Or did I make a mistake? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: What is $b^{1/3}$? Why do you think it exists? You prove the existence of the cubic root bei assuming that it exists. That makes no sense. But no one asks you to  prove the existence of the cubic root.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have $(b^{1/3})^3$ equals to $(c^{1/3})^3$, that doesn't mean that $(b^{1/3})$ equals $(c^{1/3})$. In fact, that's the very thing you're being asked to prove.

The theorem isn't true for all fields: for example, if $F=\mathbf{Z}_7$, then $x^3-1$ has three solutions, namely 1, 2 and 4.

However, you only have to prove it for ordered fields. $\mathbf{Z}_7$ is not an ordered field. Your proof will likely use the fact that the field is ordered.

Here's one such proof, but maybe you can find a simpler one:

Let $p$ and $q$ be two solutions to $x^3-b=0$, and let $p<q$ (note I'm using the fact that it's an ordered field) and let $q=p+d$.

Since $p^3-b=(p+d)^3-b=0$, it follows that $d(3p^2+3pd+d^2)=0$, but this equals $d((3p/2+d)^2+3p^2/4)$ (valid because $F$, being ordered, does not have characteristic $2$).

The only way a positive weighted sum of two squares can equal $0$ is if (because $F$ is ordered) both squares are $0$, so that means either $d=0$ or $3p/2+d=0$ and $p=0$, in which case $d=0$ anyway.

Thus $p^3=q^3$ if and only if $p=q$, hence $x^3-b=0$ has at most one solution for any $b$ (it may have no solutions).

There are probably simpler ways to prove this, but you will have to rely on the fact that the field $F$ is ordered. It's sufficient to prove that $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly monotonic.

Comment: This makes sense but why did you let $q = p + d$?

Comment: It means the condition $q>p$ becomes $d>0$, which just seemed intuitively simpler. I'm sure you can do the proof without that.

Answer (score 1):

You offer no justification for your claim that $b^{1/3} = c^{1/3} \implies b = c$.

In essence, that's what the problem requires you to prove.

As an indication that your proof is not valid, note that you never used the hypothesis that $F$ is an ordered field.

Thus, let $F$ be an ordered field, and suppose $x,y\in F$ are such that $x^3=y^3$.

We want to show $x=y$.

If $x=0$, then $x^3=0$, so $y^3=0$, hence $y=0$, so $x=y$.

Similarly, if $y=0$, then $y^3=0$, so $x^3=0$, hence $x=0$, so $x=y$.

Thus suppose $x,y\ne 0$, and assume $x\ne y$.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
x^3=y^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^3-y^3=0
\\[4pt]\implies\;&
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^2+xy+y^2=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
4x^2+4xy+4y^2=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(4x^2+4xy+y^2)+3y^2=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(2x+y)^2+3y^2=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
conradiction, since $(2x+y)^2 \ge 0$ and $3y^2 > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Why can we assume $y^3 = 0 \implies y = 0$?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I see it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this only means that "one solution is unique", you still need to show $a_1^3>a_2^3$ if $a_1,a_2 \in F$